# I need help in uploading large files in nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb

I am creating realtime andoid chat app in java, backend in  nodejs and mongodb.

I want to ask
How to save chat in mongodb?
How to upload lager files in nodejs or mongodb? I cann't upload file more than 100kb in this.

this is the code.

ChatActivity.java

```
package com.example.chat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
    AdView mAdView;
    private String name;
    private WebSocket webSocket;
    private String SERVER_PATH = "ws://group2all.com:50000/";
    private EditText messageEdit;
    private View sendBtn, pickImgBtn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int IMAGE_REQUEST_ID = 1;
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);


        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView4);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        initiateSocketConnection();

    }

    private void initiateSocketConnection() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(SERVER_PATH).build();
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new SocketListener());

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String string = s.toString().trim();

        if (string.isEmpty()) {
            resetMessageEdit();
        } else {

            sendBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pickImgBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    private void resetMessageEdit() {

        messageEdit.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        messageEdit.setText("");
        sendBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pickImgBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        messageEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }

    private class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            super.onOpen(webSocket, response);

            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,
                        "Socket Connection Successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                initializeView();
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text);

            runOnUiThread(() -> {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(text);
                    jsonObject.put("isSent", false);

                    messageAdapter.addItem(jsonObject);

                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            });

        }
    }

    private void initializeView() {

        messageEdit = findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
        sendBtn = findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
        pickImgBtn = findViewById(R.id.pickImgBtn);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        messageEdit.addTextChangedListener(this);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("name", name);
                jsonObject.put("message", messageEdit.getText().toString());

                webSocket.send(jsonObject.toString());

                jsonObject.put("isSent", true);
                messageAdapter.addItem(jsonObject);

                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

                resetMessageEdit();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        pickImgBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setType("video/*");

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pick image"),
                    IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);

        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                sendImage(image);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    private void sendImage(Bitmap image) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

        String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(),
                Base64.DEFAULT);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObject.put("name", name);
            jsonObject.put("image", base64String);

            webSocket.send(jsonObject.toString());

            jsonObject.put("isSent", true);

            messageAdapter.addItem(jsonObject);

            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This is server.js file

```
const SocketServer = require('websocket').server
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {})
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"



server.listen(50000, ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 50000...")
})

app.listen(60000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 60000...")
})

app.use(express.json())

mongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {

    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while connecting mongo client")
    } else {

        const myDb = db.db('myDb')
        const collection = myDb.collection('myTable')

        app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

            const newUser = {
                name: req.body.name,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password
            }

            const query = { email: newUser.email }

            collection.findOne(query, (err, result) => {

                if (result == null) {
                    collection.insertOne(newUser, (err, result) => {
                        res.status(200).send()
                    })
                } else {
                    res.status(400).send()
                }

            })

        })

        app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

            const query = {
                email: req.body.email, 
                password: req.body.password
            }

            collection.findOne(query, (err, result) => {

                if (result != null) {

                    const objToSend = {
                        name: result.name,
                        email: result.email
                    }

                    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(objToSend))

                } else {
                    res.status(404).send()
                }

            })

        })

    }

})

wsServer = new SocketServer({httpServer:server})

const connections = []

wsServer.on('request', (req) => {
    const connection = req.accept()
    console.log('new connection')
    connections.push(connection)

    connection.on('message', (mes) => {
        connections.forEach(element => {
            if (element != connection)
                element.sendUTF(mes.utf8Data)
        })
    })

    connection.on('close', (resCode, des) => {
        console.log('connection closed')
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(connection), 1)
    })

})
```

One more thing i want to ask in js file
Can i use one port in this at 60000?If yes how?

Please tell me code to better understanding.

Comment: Have you thought about  aws s3 buckets??

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am building on my own server.